# Injection from an integral domain to its field of fractions.

Tags: field-theory, vector-spaces, modules

I have a quick question about modules. Suppose that $R$ is an integral domain with field of fractions $K$. Then any free $R$-module is isomorphic to copies of direct sums of $R$, say $R^i$ . Furthermore, there exists an injection $R^i \rightarrow K^i$ of vector spaces.

I am not sure I understand the part about the injection. Surely one can just send $(r_1,\dots,r_i) \in R^i$ to $\left(\frac{r_1}{1},\dots,\frac{r_i}{1}\right) \in K^i$ and this defines an injection ? Is there another way to think about this ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I don't understand the "injection of *vector spaces*" thing: vector spaces...over what field?? It can't be $\,K\,$ as usually ID's aren't closed under multiplication by scalars from their fraction fields, so...?

Comment: It isn't specified...but you are right, it does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $R^i\hookrightarrow K^i$ you've defined is an injection of $R$-modules. This does make sense, because $K^i$ is a $K$-vector space, also known as a $K$-module, and hence, via the canonical injection $R\rightarrow K$, is an $R$-module (i.e. $r\in R$ acts on $K^i$, or any $K$-vector space for that matter, by its image in $K$). This is a particular case of restriction of scalars along a ring map. If $R$ and $S$ are arbitrary rings and $\varphi:R\rightarrow S$ is a ring map (I don't assume the rings are commutative but they should have $1$ and a ring map should respect this), then any $S$-module $M$ may be given the structure of an $R$-module by defining $r\cdot m=\varphi(r)m$ for any $r\in R$ and $m\in M$.